# What's the differences between `int*[1]` and `int(*)[1]`?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, type-safety, using-declaration

```
using T1 = int*[1];
using T2 = int(*)[1];

T1 t1;
T2 t2;

t1[0] = 0;   // ok
t2[0] = 0;   // error : array type 'int [1]' is not assignable
t2    = t1;  // error : array type 'int [1]' is not assignable
t2    = &t1; // error : array type 'int [1]' is not assignable
t2    = 0;   // ok
```

Why is `t2[0]`(/`t1`) not assignable?

What's the differences between `int*[1]` and `int(*)[1]`?

**Update:**

```
int n[1];
t2 = &n; // ok
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int*[1]` is an array of length 1, whose element is `int*`.

`int(*)[1]` is a pointer, which points to array `int[1]`. Thus `t2[0]` is an array `int[1]`, which is not assignable.

Comment: @szxwpmj It's obvious, what do you expect ?

Comment: @szxwpmj why would it be? `t1` is array of pointers to ints not array of ints